# Reload leaves corrupt state

Tags: bluetooth, react-native

My app connects to a bluetooth device using [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial).

Whenever I press Reload from the developer menu, the app is left in a corrupt state. It's no longer connected to the bluetooth device, which is expected. However, attempting to connect again always fails. The user must manually unpair before the app can connect again.

This problem does not occur when the app is closed or killed on the device. Nor does it occur when running `react-native run-android` on the dev machine.

I was hoping to find event handler where I can disconnect. The obvious place is `componentWillUnmount` of the main component. But it does not run in case of a reload. Is there some way to detect reload and perform clean up before things go sideways?

Comment: When app is closed, it's code is kinda "running" in background (it's state is kept, listeners stay in place, ...). When killed, well, it's killed and reinitiated on next launch. If you reload you app from dev menu, app loses all it's state, event listeners are gone, connections are gone as well. What you need to do is reinitiate listeners and connections on reload.

Comment: @Andreyco I would like to "reinitiate...connections on reload" but I can't. That's the problem. The bluetooth library has ```connect```, ```disconnect```. Calling ```connect``` after the restart rejects with an unhelpful error. Calling ```disconnect``` first does not help. Because the app is not shutting down all the way, it's state is not totally destroyed I assume. Something in the native state remains in a corrupt condition.

Comment: got it, will try to setup demo for this issue later today, to see what's possible. It's interesting issue...